# Show extra column with Promoted Links App

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, promoted-links

I am using Promoted Links app and want to show a help message with each title, text would be as "Click here for more information" and this sentence should be displayed under each tile, I should be able to define a help link url at the time of creating new tile.

Possible? I have created a help message column in the app but it doses not show along with titles.
There is a description column that shows description on mouse hover but I want to show help message all the time without any mouse hover.

Comment: I would, on doc load, grab the ID of the tile, query the list for the Help column associated, then append this below the tile div and format it how you need to

Comment: Although, I don't see a reliable way to grab the ID from these elements. You may have to query based on img src (if that is unique)